# How to resubscribe input valueChange with data stream when http error arrives

Tags: angular

I want start data stream when user change value on input. When stream received http error(40x) input observable stops and after next input value change subscription doesnt return value. How resubscribe input observable after receive http error?

This is input valueChange code.

```
this.formGroup.controls.FirstControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    untilDestroyed(this),       
    mergeMap((value) => { 
      return this.streamService
        .init("somebody", "someurl", someParams)               
      }             
  ))
  .subscribe({        
    next: response => {
      this.processStreamResponse(response);
    },
    error: err => console.info(err)
  });
```

}

This is method that returns stream observable

```
 private readonly dispatcherSubject = new ReplaySubject<MessageEvent>(1);
 private currentDispatcheSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

     public init(body: any, url: string, params: HttpParams) {
        this.releaseCurrent();
    
        // create subscription to listen events
        this.currentDispatcheSubscription = this.createMessageDispatcherObservable(body, url, params).subscribe(this.dispatcherSubject);
      }
    
      private createMessageDispatcherObservable(body: any, url: string, params: HttpParams): Observable<MessageEvent> {
        return this.sseClient
          .stream(
            `${this.gatewayApi}/${url}`,
            { keepAlive: true, reconnectionDelay: 3_000, responseType: 'event' },
            { body: body, params },
            'POST',
          )
          .pipe(       
            map(e => e as MessageEvent),
          );
      }

 public releaseCurrent() {
    if (this.currentDispatcheSubscription) {
      this.logger.log(`${LOG_NAME} - releasing stream`);
      this.currentDispatcheSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.currentDispatcheSubscription = undefined;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to try something with [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) but I don't know it very well so I let you read the docs

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when an observable errors, it completes.
You should catch the error, and the operator [`catchError`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) is what you need here:

```
private createMessageDispatcherObservable(body: any, url: string, params: HttpParams): Observable<MessageEvent> {
        return this.sseClient
          .stream(
            `${this.gatewayApi}/${url}`,
            { keepAlive: true, reconnectionDelay: 3_000, responseType: 'event' },
            { body: body, params },
            'POST',
          )
          .pipe(       
            map(e => e as MessageEvent),
            catchError(err => {
              // Handle your error and return an observable of what you need
              return of(null)
            })
          );
      }
```

Note that you need to catch all the streams that errors out.

Comment: I added catchError to pipe in createMessageDispatcherObservable method and when stream gets http error input subscribe still doesnt returns value.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is more complex and you are not showing all the parts involved, please provide a minimal reproducible example, maybe on a platform like [StackBlitzk](https://stackblitz.com/) so we can investigate on which the error is

Comment: It's also really strange that in `mergeMap` you are returning the value returned by a function that doesn't return anything (`init` doesn't return anything), the code you provided should not compile